# Is this a binary search tree ? HackerRank Problem

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

I was trying to solve the problem Is this a binary search tree from HackerRank by using Tree: level order traversal. But it's showing compilation error. Is it because of using `queue`? The hidden stub code will pass an argument in this problem. Problem link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/is-binary-search-tree/problem . Here is my code:

```
bool checkBST(Node* root) {
        if(root == NULL){
            return true;
        }

        queue<Node*> Q;
        Q.push(root);
        while(!Q.empty()){
            Node *current_node = Q.front();

            if(current_node->left != NULL){
                if(current_node->left->data >= current_node->data){
                    return false;
                }
                Q.push(current_node->left);
            }
            if(current_node->right != NULL){
                if(current_node->right->data <= current_node->data){
                    return false;
                }
                Q.push(current_node->right);
            }

            Q.pop();
        }
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a look at aforementioned hackerrank challenge, Yes, the error is you have not included `#include <queue>` but you're NOT allowed to add header files in this challenge. You must do this question with recursion.

Please feel free to ask if you want to get hints on how to write recursion.